# Javascript not working somehow - not sure what I am doing wrong :/

Tags: javascript, forms, return, onsubmit

I am not sure what is wrong so I just thought of asking you all. I want to validate some variables via JS before I send them to my PHP Script, but somehow it's not working as I want and I am not sure why. Here my example code :

HTML

```
<script src="jadd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form name="jadd" action="./func/add_job.php" method="post" onsubmit="return vf()">
<a href="javascript:document.jadd.submit()">random submit</a>
...
<input type="text" size="100" maxlength="150" name="jt" />
...
</form>
```

Javascript (jadd.js):

```
function vf() {
var x=document.forms["jadd"]["jt"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("Field must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `but somehow it's not working as I want and I am not sure why`, more details please

Comment: nothing happens - I get redirect INSTANTLY to the PHP file

Answer (score 1):

You have <del>two problems</del>edited your question.

1. When you programatically submit a form, you won't trigger the submit event. Use a real submit button (`<input type="submit">`), not a link with JavaScript instead of an HTTP URI. (You can use CSS to make a button look like a link if you really want to).
2. <del>You are trying to call a function called `vf` but you have defined a function called `vf_addjob`, you need to use the same name!</del>

Comment: 1. That did the magic ... oh jeez I hate to css around for those things :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vf_addjob()` instead of  `vf()`

should be :

```
onsubmit="return vf_addjob()"
```

Comment: Was a typo ... edited it ... the typo wasn't in the original script tho.

Comment: <a href="javascript:vf();">random submit</a> and remove form onsumbit

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your `a href...` button.
2. Add inside the `form` this `<input type="submit" value="click me">`

Should look like this:

```
<script src="jadd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form name="jadd" action="./func/add_job.php" method="post" onsubmit="return vf()">
...
<input type="text" size="100" maxlength="150" name="jt" />
...
<input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

It would also be good practice to add a `return true;` in the JS function. But that's more for code readability.